# awk regx not working with string from file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I want to check string from file with below condition but it gives me an error

```
awk 'NR > 1 {print $2,"-",if(length($2) >=8 && $2 ~ "[A-Z_][A-Z_0-9]+") print "OK" else print "No"}}' file.txt
```

**Error**

```
 awk: cmd. line:1: NR > 1 {print $2,"-",if(length($2) >=8) print "OK" else print "No"}}
    awk: cmd. line:1:                      ^ syntax error
    awk: cmd. line:1: NR > 1 {print $2,"-",if(length($2) >=8) print "OK" else print "No"}}
    awk: cmd. line:1:                                         ^ syntax error
    awk: cmd. line:1: NR > 1 {print $2,"-",if(length($2) >=8) print "OK" else print "No"}}
    awk: cmd. line:1: 

                                                                   ^ syntax error
```

I think there is syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some braces and semicolons are missing here and there

```sh
awk 'NR > 1 {print $2,"-"; if(length($2) >=8 && $2 ~ "[A-Z_][A-Z_0-9]+") { print "OK"} else { print "No" }}' file.txt
```

And this is independed of whatever you are trying to do, which you haven't explained yet.